# Applescript menu bar item toggle if title of attribute is... (or exists)

Tags: xcode, applescript, automator

I need a applescript that clicks a menu item if the title of the item has a specific name.
Here the concrete case (Sorry... I'm not allowed to embed pictures yet, so please click):

[image]

[image]

If the menu item 2 is "Enable calibration" it should be clicked. If the title is "Disable calibration" it should stop (I just put a "false" for testing in the code).

Here my first code but it doesn't work (Syntaxerror):

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SoundID Reference"
    if the title of the attribute "AXMenuItem" is "Disable calibration" then click it
        else
            return false
    end if
end tell
```

My second try was with the code "exists" but it doesn't work as well (just nothing happens):

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SoundID Reference"
    if menu item "Enable calibration" of menu 1 exists then click it
end tell
```

So any advices how I could solve this?

Comment: You need to use a _complete reference_ to the menu item to get the name and perform clicks, for example `tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Script Editor" to set theMenuItem to menu item 1 of menu "Spelling and Grammar" of menu item "Spelling and Grammar" of menu "Edit" of menu bar item "Edit" of menu bar 1`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! And please forgive, but I just started with this „coding thing“. So I don’t understand where in your suggestion is the „click“? How exactly should the code look like in my case? Thank you!

Comment: Here the codes I tried:

`tell application "System Events" to tell process "SoundID Reference" tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of menu item 2 of menu bar 2 if menu item "Enable calibration" exists then click it end tell end tell`

Nothing happens.

Comment: or: `tell application "System Events" to tell process "SoundID Reference" tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of menu item 2 of menu bar 2 if the title of the attribute "AXMenuItem" is "Enable calibration" then click it end tell end tell`

Syntax error (... can't be read).

Comment: I don’t have that application, but your menu reference is backward.  it should be bottom up with the form `menu item X of menu Y of menu bar item Y of menu Z of menu bar item Z of menu bar 1` (menu bar 1 is the main menu bar).

Comment: Thank you again for your help! I tried to get the menu references with UI Browser (see screenshots), but it seems that this software doesn't show the right names (?). So finally I found a solution with the `try`-command. Seems this is easier. But again... thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found another solution how to solve this problem with the "try"-command:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SoundID Reference"
tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    try
        click menu item "Enable calibration" of menu 1
    end try
end tell
end tell
```